# What is the blank portion in "Application Server" window in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, application-server

This is bugging me since so long, What is this blank area in Application Server in Intellij?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application servers view shares the UI template with the other clouds or server-like tool-windows, e.g with Docker view.

In this UI template, the right panel is intended to show the details for the selected main node, but app server integrations don’t currently provide any useful info to show, hence it is at the moment blank.

For 2019.1 release we are considering adding some more information here, so if you have any requests for particular bits, please don’t hesitate to suggest.